# Buildozer built app crashes after showing the presplash screen

Tags: python, python-3.x, kivy, buildozer, kivymd

I am new to kivy and it's my first build with the kivy, I used google collab for the compilation environment ,Error is very time  open my app it loads and shows pre splash screen and then it crashes, I have also tried adb for getting logs but it doesn't give any info,
[here is the link to the apk](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1NUHxzlHscVsXK3xXG6rB9Jvfh2NcDp3Z/view?usp=sharing)

here is my app code

```
#importing necessary things 
from random import choice
import random
from kivymd.app import MDApp
from kivy.lang import Builder
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen,ScreenManager
from kivymd.uix.picker import MDThemePicker

#a variable for random choice
link=''
url=''
A=[]
vegetable=''
links = {
'Potato':'https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLVO6FhTBHcs9VPKBEhestJHUbuG3NLTM_',
'Began':'https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLVO6FhTBHcs9P9EYknoU13xewOyYwYUy0',
'LadyFinger':'https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLVO6FhTBHcs8zCG68C--OVtaYVI__6Ecc',
'BellPeper':'https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLVO6FhTBHcs-NqSpUHIYRfgsag2hQNt8X',
'Tomato':'https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLVO6FhTBHcs9n1Hon82aZ-n3TsKCJ9gxf',
'Bitter':'https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLVO6FhTBHcs-yvv0mny0smGgmz0gIABhx',
'Beans':'https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLVO6FhTBHcs-biT-0185H95RmOsGImQzJ',
'Pumbkin':'https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLVO6FhTBHcs86L_pNYr-nHOvk9w-kBC82',
'Loki':'https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLVO6FhTBHcs_ZdcJITn2C383LEBfsFRDD',
'CauliFLower':'https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLVO6FhTBHcs-lhGiDdBKcOEVp_rg8JFfZ',
'Spniach':'https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLVO6FhTBHcs8zpYHvVqZJuBY_Ct981Znh',
'Cabbage':'https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLVO6FhTBHcs-QHRxmaz2OSo9H8fbVvmX0'
}

screen_helper='''
ScreenManager:
    MainScreen:
    AboutScreen:
    DecideScreen:
    ResultScreen:
<MainScreen>:
    name:'Main' 
    MDToolbar:
        id: toolbar
        pos_hint: {"top": 1}
        elevation: 10
        title: "Main"
        left_action_items:[["menu", lambda x: nav_drawer.set_state("open")]]
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text:'Decide Now'
        pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.8}
        on_press:
            root.manager.current='Decide'
            root.manager.transition.direction='left'
    Image:
        size_hint_y:None
        size_hint_x:None
        pos_hint:{'center_y':0.29,'center_x':0.5}
        width:350
        height:350
        source:'girl121-removebg (1).png'
        keep_ratio:False
        allow_strech:True
    MDNavigationDrawer:
        id:nav_drawer
        ScrollView:
            MDList:
                OneLineIconListItem:
                    text:"About"
                    on_press:
                        root.manager.current='About'
                    IconLeftWidget:
                        icon:"alert-circle-outline"
                OneLineIconListItem:
                    text:"Set Theme"
                    on_press:
                        app.show_theme_picker()   
                    IconLeftWidget:
                        icon:"cog-outline"
                    
<AboutScreen>:
    name:'About'
    MDLabel:
        halign:'center'
        text:"This is a simple app designed for indian households created and developed by Anuj"
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text:'Back'
        pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.2}
        on_press:
            root.manager.current='Main'
            root.manager.transition.direction='right' 
<DecideScreen>
    name:'Decide'
    MDToolbar:
        id: toolbar
        pos_hint: {"top": 1}
        elevation: 10
        title: "Decide"
        left_action_items:[["arrow-left-circle-outline",lambda x:root.main_screen()]]
        right_action_items:[["arrow-right-circle-outline",lambda x:root.result_screen()]]
    ScrollView:
        size_hint_y:0.89
        MDList:
            OneLineAvatarListItem:
                text:'Allu / Potato'  
                ImageLeftWidget:
                    source:'potato.png'
                MDCheckbox:
                    on_active:app.on_checkbox_active(*args,text='Potato')
                    size_hint:(None,None)
                    pos_hint:{'center_x':0.8,'center_y':0.5}
                    size:dp(40),dp(40)
            OneLineAvatarListItem:
                text:'Began / Brinjal'    
                ImageLeftWidget:
                    source:'eggplant1.png'
                MDCheckbox:
                    on_active:app.on_checkbox_active(*args,text='Began')
                    size_hint:(None,None)
                    pos_hint:{'center_x':0.8,'center_y':0.5}
                    size:dp(40),dp(40)
            OneLineAvatarListItem:
                text:'Bhindi / Lady Finger'  
                ImageLeftWidget:
                    source:'okra.png'
                MDCheckbox:
                    on_active:app.on_checkbox_active(*args,text='LadyFinger')
                    size_hint:(None,None)
                    pos_hint:{'center_x':0.8,'center_y':0.5}
                    size:dp(40),dp(40)
            OneLineAvatarListItem:
                text:'Shimla Mirch / Bell Peper'  
                ImageLeftWidget:
                    source:'Bell-pepper.png'
                MDCheckbox:
                    on_active:app.on_checkbox_active(*args,text='BellPeper')
                    size_hint:(None,None)
                    pos_hint:{'center_x':0.8,'center_y':0.5}
                    size:dp(40),dp(40)
            OneLineAvatarListItem:
                text:'Tamatar / Tomato'
                ImageLeftWidget:
                    source:'Tomato.png'
                MDCheckbox:
                    on_active:app.on_checkbox_active(*args,text='Tomato')
                    size_hint:(None,None)
                    pos_hint:{'center_x':0.8,'center_y':0.5}
                    size:dp(40),dp(40)
            OneLineAvatarListItem:
                text:'Kerela / Bitter Gourd'
                ImageLeftWidget:
                    source:'Bittter.png'
                MDCheckbox:
                    on_active:app.on_checkbox_active(*args,text='Bitter')
                    size_hint:(None,None)
                    pos_hint:{'center_x':0.8,'center_y':0.5}
                    size:dp(40),dp(40)
            OneLineAvatarListItem:
                text:'Barbati / Sring Beans'
                ImageLeftWidget:
                    source:'green-beans.png'
                MDCheckbox:
                    on_active:app.on_checkbox_active(*args,text='Beans')
                    size_hint:(None,None)
                    pos_hint:{'center_x':0.8,'center_y':0.5}
                    size:dp(40),dp(40)

            OneLineAvatarListItem:
                text:'Kaddu / Pumbkin'
                ImageLeftWidget:
                    source:'pumpkin.png'
                MDCheckbox:
                    on_active:app.on_checkbox_active(*args,text='Pumbkin')
                    size_hint:(None,None)
                    pos_hint:{'center_x':0.8,'center_y':0.5}
                    size:dp(40),dp(40)
            
            OneLineAvatarListItem:
                text:'Loki /Bottel Gourd'
                ImageLeftWidget:
                    source:'loki.png'
                MDCheckbox:
                    on_active:app.on_checkbox_active(*args,text='Loki')
                    size_hint:(None,None)
                    pos_hint:{'center_x':0.8,'center_y':0.5}
                    size:dp(40),dp(40)

            OneLineAvatarListItem:
                text:'Gobhi /Cauli Flower'
                ImageLeftWidget:
                    source:'cauliflower.png'
                MDCheckbox:
                    on_active:app.on_checkbox_active(*args,text='CauliFLower')
                    size_hint:(None,None)
                    pos_hint:{'center_x':0.8,'center_y':0.5}
                    size:dp(40),dp(40)

            OneLineAvatarListItem:
                text:'Palak / Spniach'
                ImageLeftWidget:
                    source:'spinach.png'
                MDCheckbox:
                    on_active:app.on_checkbox_active(*args,text='Spniach')
                    size_hint:(None,None)
                    pos_hint:{'center_x':0.8,'center_y':0.5}
                    size:dp(40),dp(40)

            OneLineAvatarListItem:
                text:'Patta Gobhi / Cabbage'
                ImageLeftWidget:
                    source:'cabbage (1).png'
                MDCheckbox:
                    on_active:app.on_checkbox_active(*args,text='Cabbage')
                    size_hint:(None,None)
                    pos_hint:{'center_x':0.8,'center_y':0.5}
                    size:dp(40),dp(40)
<ResultScreen>
    name:'Result'
    MDToolbar:
        id: toolbar
        pos_hint: {"top": 1}
        elevation: 10
        title: "Decide"
        left_action_items:[["arrow-left-circle-outline",lambda x:root.decide_screen()]]
        
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text:'Back'
        pos_hint:{'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.2}
        on_press:
            root.manager.current='Decide'
            root.manager.transition.direction='right'
    MDRectangleFlatButton:
        text: 'Click to View'
        pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5,'center_y':0.5}
        on_press: 
            import webbrowser
            webbrowser.open(app.get())
'''
#initilizing all the screens and defining the methods inside them 
# if they have some 
class MainScreen(Screen):
    pass 
class AboutScreen(Screen):
    pass
class DecideScreen(Screen):
    def main_screen(self):
        MDApp.get_running_app().root.current='Main' 
        MDApp.get_running_app().root.transition.direction='right'
    def result_screen(self):
        MDApp.get_running_app().root.current='Result' 
        MDApp.get_running_app().root.transition.direction='left'
    
    
class ResultScreen(Screen):
    def decide_screen(self):
        MDApp.get_running_app().root.current='Decide' 
        MDApp.get_running_app().root.transition.direction='right'
#initilizing screen manager
sm=ScreenManager()
#adding the screens to the screen
sm.add_widget(MainScreen(name='Main'))
sm.add_widget(AboutScreen(name='About'))
sm.add_widget(DecideScreen(name='Decide'))
sm.add_widget(ResultScreen(name='Result'))
#main class fro the app and methods for app.root actions
class Main(MDApp):
#loading the string
    def build(self):
        #self.theme_cls.primary_palette= 'Green'
        screen=Builder.load_string(screen_helper)
        return screen
# a method that will  check check box is active or not
    def on_checkbox_active(self,checkbox,value,text):
        global A
        if value:
            A.append(text)
        else:
            A.remove(text)
#method for deciding a random element
    def get(self):
        global vegetable,links,url,link
        vegetable=random.choice(A)
        link = (links.get(vegetable))
        url = link
        return url
    def show_theme_picker(self):
        theme_dialog = MDThemePicker()
        theme_dialog.open()
#running main app 
Main().run()
```

and here is my buildozer spec file

```
[app]

# (str) Title of your application
title = kya banau

# (str) Package name
package.name = kyabanau
# (str) Package domain (needed for android/ios packaging)
package.domain = org.kya

# (str) Source code where the main.py live
source.dir = .

# (list) Source files to include (let empty to include all the files)
source.include_exts = py,png,jpg,kv,atlas

# (list) List of inclusions using pattern matching
#source.include_patterns = assets/*,images/*.png

# (list) Source files to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_exts = spec

# (list) List of directory to exclude (let empty to not exclude anything)
#source.exclude_dirs = tests, bin

# (list) List of exclusions using pattern matching
#source.exclude_patterns = license,images/*/*.jpg

# (str) Application versioning (method 1)
version = 0.1

# (str) Application versioning (method 2)
# version.regex = __version__ = ['"](.*)['"]
# version.filename = %(source.dir)s/main.py

# (list) Application requirements
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy,kivymd

# (str) Custom source folders for requirements
# Sets custom source for any requirements with recipes
# requirements.source.kivy = ../../kivy

# (list) Garden requirements
#garden_requirements =

# (str) Presplash of the application
#presplash.filename = %(source.dir)s/presplash.png

# (str) Icon of the application
#icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/menu.png

# (str) Supported orientation (one of landscape, sensorLandscape, portrait or all)
orientation = portrait

# (list) List of service to declare
#services = NAME:ENTRYPOINT_TO_PY,NAME2:ENTRYPOINT2_TO_PY

#
# OSX Specific
#

#
# author = © Copyright Info

# change the major version of python used by the app
osx.python_version = 3

# Kivy version to use
osx.kivy_version = 1.9.1

#
# Android specific
#

# (bool) Indicate if the application should be fullscreen or not
fullscreen = 0

# (string) Presplash background color (for new android toolchain)
# Supported formats are: #RRGGBB #AARRGGBB or one of the following names:
# red, blue, green, black, white, gray, cyan, magenta, yellow, lightgray,
# darkgray, grey, lightgrey, darkgrey, aqua, fuchsia, lime, maroon, navy,
# olive, purple, silver, teal.
#android.presplash_color = #FFFFFF

# (list) Permissions
android.permissions = INTERNET

# (int) Target Android API, should be as high as possible.
#android.api = 27

# (int) Minimum API your APK will support.
#android.minapi = 21

# (int) Android SDK version to use
#android.sdk = 20

# (str) Android NDK version to use
#android.ndk = 19b

# (int) Android NDK API to use. This is the minimum API your app will support, it should usually match android.minapi.
#android.ndk_api = 21

# (bool) Use --private data storage (True) or --dir public storage (False)
#android.private_storage = True

# (str) Android NDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ndk_path =

# (str) Android SDK directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.sdk_path =

# (str) ANT directory (if empty, it will be automatically downloaded.)
#android.ant_path =

# (bool) If True, then skip trying to update the Android sdk
# This can be useful to avoid excess Internet downloads or save time
# when an update is due and you just want to test/build your package
# android.skip_update = False

# (bool) If True, then automatically accept SDK license
# agreements. This is intended for automation only. If set to False,
# the default, you will be shown the license when first running
# buildozer.
# android.accept_sdk_license = False

# (str) Android entry point, default is ok for Kivy-based app
#android.entrypoint = org.renpy.android.PythonActivity

# (str) Android app theme, default is ok for Kivy-based app
# android.apptheme = "@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"

# (list) Pattern to whitelist for the whole project
#android.whitelist =

# (str) Path to a custom whitelist file
#android.whitelist_src =

# (str) Path to a custom blacklist file
#android.blacklist_src =

# (list) List of Java .jar files to add to the libs so that pyjnius can access
# their classes. Don't add jars that you do not need, since extra jars can slow
# down the build process. Allows wildcards matching, for example:
# OUYA-ODK/libs/*.jar
#android.add_jars = foo.jar,bar.jar,path/to/more/*.jar

# (list) List of Java files to add to the android project (can be java or a
# directory containing the files)
#android.add_src =

# (list) Android AAR archives to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.add_aars =

# (list) Gradle dependencies to add (currently works only with sdl2_gradle
# bootstrap)
#android.gradle_dependencies =

# (list) add java compile options
# this can for example be necessary when importing certain java libraries using the 'android.gradle_dependencies' option
# see https://developer.android.com/studio/write/java8-support for further information
# android.add_compile_options = "sourceCompatibility = 1.8", "targetCompatibility = 1.8"

# (list) Gradle repositories to add {can be necessary for some android.gradle_dependencies}
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.gradle_repositories = "maven { url 'https://kotlin.bintray.com/ktor' }"
#android.add_gradle_repositories =

# (list) packaging options to add 
# see https://google.github.io/android-gradle-dsl/current/com.android.build.gradle.internal.dsl.PackagingOptions.html
# can be necessary to solve conflicts in gradle_dependencies
# please enclose in double quotes 
# e.g. android.add_packaging_options = "exclude 'META-INF/common.kotlin_module'", "exclude 'META-INF/*.kotlin_module'"
#android.add_gradle_repositories =

# (list) Java classes to add as activities to the manifest.
#android.add_activities = com.example.ExampleActivity

# (str) OUYA Console category. Should be one of GAME or APP
# If you leave this blank, OUYA support will not be enabled
#android.ouya.category = GAME

# (str) Filename of OUYA Console icon. It must be a 732x412 png image.
#android.ouya.icon.filename = %(source.dir)s/data/ouya_icon.png

# (str) XML file to include as an intent filters in <activity> tag
#android.manifest.intent_filters =

# (str) launchMode to set for the main activity
#android.manifest.launch_mode = standard

# (list) Android additional libraries to copy into libs/armeabi
#android.add_libs_armeabi = libs/android/*.so
#android.add_libs_armeabi_v7a = libs/android-v7/*.so
#android.add_libs_arm64_v8a = libs/android-v8/*.so
#android.add_libs_x86 = libs/android-x86/*.so
#android.add_libs_mips = libs/android-mips/*.so

# (bool) Indicate whether the screen should stay on
# Don't forget to add the WAKE_LOCK permission if you set this to True
#android.wakelock = False

# (list) Android application meta-data to set (key=value format)
#android.meta_data =

# (list) Android library project to add (will be added in the
# project.properties automatically.)
#android.library_references =

# (list) Android shared libraries which will be added to AndroidManifest.xml using <uses-library> tag
#android.uses_library =

# (str) Android logcat filters to use
#android.logcat_filters = *:S python:D

# (bool) Copy library instead of making a libpymodules.so
#android.copy_libs = 1

# (str) The Android arch to build for, choices: armeabi-v7a, arm64-v8a, x86, x86_64
android.arch = armeabi-v7a

# (int) overrides automatic versionCode computation (used in build.gradle)
# this is not the same as app version and should only be edited if you know what you're doing
# android.numeric_version = 1

#
# Python for android (p4a) specific
#

# (str) python-for-android fork to use, defaults to upstream (kivy)
#p4a.fork = kivy

# (str) python-for-android branch to use, defaults to master
#p4a.branch = master

# (str) python-for-android git clone directory (if empty, it will be automatically cloned from github)
#p4a.source_dir =

# (str) The directory in which python-for-android should look for your own build recipes (if any)
#p4a.local_recipes =

# (str) Filename to the hook for p4a
#p4a.hook =

# (str) Bootstrap to use for android builds
# p4a.bootstrap = sdl2

# (int) port number to specify an explicit --port= p4a argument (eg for bootstrap flask)
#p4a.port =


#
# iOS specific
#

# (str) Path to a custom kivy-ios folder
#ios.kivy_ios_dir = ../kivy-ios
# Alternately, specify the URL and branch of a git checkout:
ios.kivy_ios_url = https://github.com/kivy/kivy-ios
ios.kivy_ios_branch = master

# Another platform dependency: ios-deploy
# Uncomment to use a custom checkout
#ios.ios_deploy_dir = ../ios_deploy
# Or specify URL and branch
ios.ios_deploy_url = https://github.com/phonegap/ios-deploy
ios.ios_deploy_branch = 1.7.0

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the debug version
# Get a list of available identities: buildozer ios list_identities
#ios.codesign.debug = "iPhone Developer: <lastname> <firstname> (<hexstring>)"

# (str) Name of the certificate to use for signing the release version
#ios.codesign.release = %(ios.codesign.debug)s


[buildozer]

# (int) Log level (0 = error only, 1 = info, 2 = debug (with command output))
log_level = 2

# (int) Display warning if buildozer is run as root (0 = False, 1 = True)
warn_on_root = 1

# (str) Path to build artifact storage, absolute or relative to spec file
# build_dir = ./.buildozer

# (str) Path to build output (i.e. .apk, .ipa) storage
# bin_dir = ./bin

#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    List as sections
#
#    You can define all the "list" as [section:key].
#    Each line will be considered as a option to the list.
#    Let's take [app] / source.exclude_patterns.
#    Instead of doing:
#
#[app]
#source.exclude_patterns = license,data/audio/*.wav,data/images/original/*
#
#    This can be translated into:
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns]
#license
#data/audio/*.wav
#data/images/original/*
#


#    -----------------------------------------------------------------------------
#    Profiles
#
#    You can extend section / key with a profile
#    For example, you want to deploy a demo version of your application without
#    HD content. You could first change the title to add "(demo)" in the name
#    and extend the excluded directories to remove the HD content.
#
#[app@demo]
#title = My Application (demo)
#
#[app:source.exclude_patterns@demo]
#images/hd/*
#
#    Then, invoke the command line with the "demo" profile:
#
#buildozer --profile demo android debug
```

[and log file ,I get from the adb logcat](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1STZUYDSb6egmLW4YD4tgvCCI5vwsyrYN/view?usp=sharing)
and ,I think 1460 is related to the app in the logs
,I am using real me 3 android 11
please help , thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to install specific `kivy` version. The best version is `kivy 2.0.0rc4`. You can download it in plugins section which ever program you are using for coding. Default `kivy` version which is `kivy 2.0.0` has a bug. It was crashing for me too. So in `buildozer.spec` replace it with this:

```
# comma separated e.g. requirements = sqlite3,kivy
requirements = python3,kivy==2.0.0rc4,kivymd==0.104.2
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a tip for using the log.txt ,
instead of this , you can use real-time logs and it filters only python log here is the command..

It can be hard to look for errors in log.txt , best method is to search for these keyword.
**No Module, No NameError , Traceback , indentation error**

Command to filter python logs while deployin on device

`buildozer android debug deploy run logcat | grep python`